# shell for loop to read files inside a directory

Tags: shell

I have comma separated files in directory I want to read all files using for loop, tried following code

```
echo on

cd \tmp\Documents

`for /r %%i in (*csv) do "hello World" %%i`
```

getting 2 errors

```
1. Syntax Error near unexpected token '%%i'
2. $'/r' command not found
```

please help me to sort it out

Comment: I cannot really get a clear picture of the type of Shell you are using. Is this Linux or Windows or another OS? Could you shed some light on this (type of shell and OS?)

Comment: @Noor: The syntax does look like Windows cmd shell or maybe Powershell, not POSIX shell. Plesae tag your question appropriately.

Comment: The `[shell]` tag means POSIX shell on Unix/Linux -- it has nothing to do with the DOS `[batch-file]` tag... You have mixed apples and orange. Please clarify if you are using a DOS batch file on DOS/windows or are trying to write a shell script on Linux.

Comment: This code is for windows batch file I agree, what are the changes do I need to make in the code so I can run this in linux environment??

Answer (score 1):

you can try this - just replace the  `DIR_TO_READ_FROM`  with the directory where you are  storing the CSV

```sh
for file in "${DIR_TO_READ_FROM}"/*.csv
do
  echo "$file"
done
```